# Least $n$ for which an estimation holds

Tags: calculus

For $x\in (-1,1)$ **fixed** and $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$, let

$$g_n(x) :=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}x^k$$

1) Prove by induction that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$,  $\ln(1+x)=g_n(x)+\displaystyle\int_0^x(-1)^n\dfrac{t^n}{1+t}dt$  (*done*)

2) Let $R_n(x) :=\displaystyle\int_0^x(-1)^n\dfrac{t^n}{1+t}dt$
prove that $(R_n(x))_n$ converges to $0$ and deduce that

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) = \ln(1+x)$$  (*done*)

3) Let $x=-\dfrac 12$
Find the least natural number $n_0$ such that 
$n\ge n_0 \implies \left|\ln\left(\dfrac 12\right)-g_n\left(-\dfrac 12\right)\right|<10^{-2}$

Any ideas for this last question ? The problem gives no information about whether the use of calculator is allowed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\left|\ln \dfrac{1}{2}-g_n\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right|=\left|\int_{0}^{-1/2}(-1)^{n}\dfrac{t^n}{1+t}dx\right|.$$

[Evaluate the integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20t%5En%2F(1%2Bt)%20dt) for different values of $n$ and see for which $n$ the value becomes smaller than $10^{-2}$

Comment: Thanks, I've used your idea to find out that the integral is $<0.01$ as soon as $ n \ge 5$.
it remains to prove that the integral is $>0.01$ for $n=4$